# Call another notebook and get variables from it

Tags: azure-synapse

I'm calling another notebook that reads some data from files, and I want to pass the variables with the read data back to the calling notebook. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is not supported to get variables from the called notebook in Synapse.
We can call one notebook from another using the below command.

```
mssparkutils.notebook.run("notebook path", <timeoutSeconds>, <parameters>)
```

To exit from the called notebook we can use this command like return in normal functions.

```
mssparkutils.notebook.exit("value string")
```

This function only **supports to return a string value** to the calling notebook.
So, to get the file data variable from the called notebook we can have a temporary solution. That is using **Temporary views**.

Temporary views have a scope in the spark session of the calling notebook. When we call the notebook, it will execute in the spark session of the calling notebook, and **we can access the temporary views which are created in callee as the views are created in the same spark session**.

Here **Notebook1 is the Caller** and **sample2 is the callee**.

***Code in Notebook1:***

```
from notebookutils import mssparkutils 
returned_dfview = mssparkutils.notebook.run("/sample2") 
df2=spark.sql("select * from {0}".format(returned_dfview)) 
df2.show()
```

You can see that I am able to show my sample data which was read in callee using temporary view.

[image]

When you click on the **`View notebook run: sample2`**, you can see the executed code and output of the callee notebook.

***sample2 code:***

```
# read your files as dataframes 
df.createOrReplaceTempView("dftable") 
mssparkutils.notebook.exit("dftable")
```

We are getting the dataframe by **returning the name of the temporary view** in exit function.

[image]

If you want to get the data of multiple files, then **create the temporary views for all** and pass the **names of them as an array**. The `exit()` will **return the array as a string to the Caller** like below for example.

```
"['view1','view2','view3']"
```

Please follow below code to get the dataframes from the string.

```
exec(f'tempview_list = {source_views}') 
dfs={} 
for i in tempview_list: 
    df_name="{0}_df".format(i) 
    dfs[df_name]=spark.sql("select * from {0}".format(i))
```

Here `source_views` is the **returned string of views**. The above code converts the string to the array of views and stores the **dataframes from it in a dictionary** with the names like `view1_df`, `view2_df`.

[image]

If you don’t want to do it with temporary views as they only have a scope in their spark session you can try with global views in synapse like this [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/notebook-workflows#python-1).

Txt files can be passed as string and for JSON files you can try code in the above documentation in Synapse.

***NOTE:*** Make sure you **publish the callee notebook before executing the code** in caller notebook.