# Calling referenced functions after mssparkutil.notebook.run?

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-synapse, spark-notebook

How can I call functions defined in a different Synapse notebook after running the notebook with `mssparkutils.notebook.run()`?

example:

```
#parameters
value = "test"
```

```
from notebookutils import mssparkutils

mssparkutils.notebook.run("function definitions", 60, {"param": value})
```

```
df = load_cosmos_data() #defined in 'function definitions' notebook
```

This fails with: `NameError: name 'load_cosmos_data' is not defined`

I can use the functions with the `%run` command, but I need to be able to pass the parameter through to the `function definitions` notebook. `%run` doesn't allow me to pass a variable as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through this [Official Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/microsoft-spark-utilities?pivots=programming-language-python&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-4020762#exit-a-notebook),

> When referencing other notebook, after the exit from the referenced
> notebook with `exit()` or without that, the source notebook script will
> be executed and they will become two different notebooks which have no
> relationship between them. **We can’t access any variable from that
> notebook, and it applies to the functions of that notebook** as well.

In general programming languages as well, we can’t access the variables of a function which are local to it after its return. It is only possible when we return that variable.

Unfortunately, the `exit()` method **doesn’t support returning values other than strings** from the referenced notebook.

From the above code, assuming that you need to access the dataframe which is returning from the function `load_cosmos_data()` in referenced notebook. You can do it using the **temporary views**.

Please follow the demonstration below:

In the referenced notebook ***call the function*** and ***store the returned dataframe*** in a variable and ***create a temporary view*** for that. You can store this temporary view ***as dataframe in the source notebook***.

***Function Notebook:***
**Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
def load_data():
    data2 = [(24,"Rakesh","Govindula"),
        (16,"Virat","Kohli")]
    schema = StructType([ \
        StructField("id",IntegerType(),True), \
        StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
        StructField("lastname",StringType(),True)
    ])
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2,schema=schema)
    return df

df2=load_data()
df2.show()    
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("dataframeview")
mssparkutils.notebook.exit("dataframeview")
```

[image]

***Source Notebook:***
**Code:**

```
value="test"
from notebookutils import mssparkutils
view_name=mssparkutils.notebook.run("/function_notebook", 60, {"param": value})   
df=spark.sql("select * from {0}".format(view_name))
df.show()
```

[image]

With this approach you can **pass the parameter through to function notebook** and can **access the dataframe returned from the function** as well.

Please go through this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72734204/call-another-notebook-and-get-variables-from-it/72743469#72743469) if you face any issues when returning values from synapse notebook.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `mssparkutils.notebook.run()` if you want to access functions or variables in the notebook you are running. You have to use the magic command `%run`.

From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks#run-notebooks):

> You can use %run  magic command to reference another notebook within current notebook's context. All the variables defined in the reference notebook are available in the current notebook.

No idea what magic this command is doing, but while both approaches can call a referenced notebook, only `%run` will return its context.